# Sum returns wrong value when joining same table twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `parent` and a `child` table, and the `child` table can reference itself via a foreign key assigned to the `ref_id` column.

I am trying to execute a sum which will return the parent id (`parent_id`) and the sum of the `value` column of its children, plus the sum of the `value` column on rows where the value referenced in `ref_id` points to a child of the current parent. On the other hand, rows where `ref_id` is not null should not be added to the sum of their own parent.

However, when I execute the sum it adds the value of each referenced child times the amount of times referenced. For example, if child of id `1` and value `11.35` is referenced three times, `34.05` is added to the sum instead of `11.35`.

This is my structure:

```
create table parent(
  parent_id int auto_increment primary key
);

create table child(
  child_id int auto_increment primary key,
  parent_id int not null,
  value decimal(19,2) not null,
  ref_id int null,
  foreign key (parent_id) references parent (parent_id),
  foreign key (ref_id) references child (child_id)
);
```

And this is my sample data:

```
parent: (1), (2)

child:
    (1, 1, 11.35, null),
    (2, 1, 38.37, null),
    (3, 1, 65.46, null),
    (4, 2, 289.42, 1),
    (5, 2, 978.35, 1),
    (6, 2, 1669.19, 1)
```

When I execute this query:

```
select p.parent_id as parent_id, (ifnull(sum(c1.value), 0) + ifnull(sum(c2.value), 0)) as total
from parent as p
left join child as c1 on (p.parent_id = c1.parent_id and c1.ref_id is null)
left join child as c2 on (c1.child_id = c2.ref_id)
group by p.parent_id;
```

I expect this result:

```
parent_id: 1, total: 3052.14
parent_id: 2, total: 0.00
```

Instead, I get this result:

```
parent_id: 1, total: 3074.84
parent_id: 2, total: 0.00
```

Why? And how do I fix it?

**Edit:** Here's a fiddle with my issue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7fedf/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `11.35` is multiplexed three times for `c1.child_id = c2.ref_id` matching condition in your case, and difference `34.05` is due to this.
Consider seperately joining those two tables twice and combine by using `union` :

```
select sum(q.val) from
(
select (ifnull(c2.value, 0) ) as val
  from child as c1 
  left join child as c2 on c1.child_id = c2.ref_id  
union all
select ( ifnull(c.value, 0))
  from parent as p 
  left join child as c on p.parent_id = c.parent_id and c.ref_id is null 
) q
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f3fefd86d4a37b2cf9ff3be2239904bb)</kbd>

Comment: That looks nice, I'll try it out later

Answer (score 0):

try to get  sum of distinct values.
If did not work then let me know i will provide you the next solution as you know one issue has many solutions before a final solution.

Comment: That won't work because the `value` column is not unique